# if condition in shell script - error token - digits 8 and 9 in date output

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following shell script:

```
prodStartTime="213000"  
prodEndTime="235959"  
currentTime=`date +"%H%M%S"`  

if [[ ${currentTime} -ge ${prodStartTime#0} && ${currentTime} -le ${prodEndTime#0} ]];  
then  
    echo "Something .........."  
else  
    echo "Else part Something .........."  
fi
```

Getting Error

> **"line 5: prodStartTime: 043058: value too great for base (error token is "043058")"**

This error occurs when 8 or 9 are present in hours or minutes.

Example:

(error token is "043058")
(error token is "043059")
(error token is "043850")
(error token is "043901")

Comment: Which platform are you using? Working fine for me and How are you running the script?

Comment: linux platform  . automated cron job.. If i run manually  getting error  \./a.sh

Comment: Sorry typo error ./a.sh

Comment: Note that your error message doesn't agree with the posted code; `productStartTime` does not begin with a 0, although *`currentTime`* might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest and clearest fix is to use *string* comparison rather than *numeric* comparison:

```
prodStartTime=213000
prodEndTime=235959
currentTime="$(date +%H%M%S)"

if [[ $currentTime > $prodStartTime && $currentTime < $prodEndTime ]] ; then
    echo "Something .........."  
else
    echo "Else part Something .........."  
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because time strings with leading zero are being interpreted as octal numbers instead of decimal.

To prevent this, change your date assignment this way which strips off leading zeros if any:

```
currentTime=`date +"%-H%M%S"`
```

Read more about zero padding in `date` here: [Removing leading zeros from DATE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79371/removing-leading-zeros-from-date)

Comment: But the same problem will happen tonight at 8 minutes past midnight!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure Bash understands your number in radix 10 as follows:

```
currentTime=$(( 10#$(date +"%H%M%S") ))
```

The `10#` prefix forces radix 10. See the end of [this paragraph of the reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

Could you change one of these;

```
currentTime=`date +"%k%M%S"`
```

or

```
currentTime=`date +"_H%M%S"`
```

man date :

%k     hour, space padded ( 0..23); same as %_H

%H     hour (00..23)

Comment: And the same problem will happen tonight at 8 minutes past midnight!